# Why does one counter work and the other doesn't? (Closures?)

Tags: javascript

I have two questions about this counter example.

1. Why doesn't addVersionOne work? Why is it returning the actual code instead of a number?
2. How does addVersionTwo work? Isn't `counter` being reset back to `0` every time the function is run?

```js
const addVersionOne = function() {
  let counter = 0;
  return function() {
    counter += 1;
    return counter;
  }
}

var addVersionTwo = (function () {
  let counter = 0;
  return function() {
    counter += 1; 
    return counter;
  }
})();

function writeVersionOne(){
  document.getElementById("addVersionOne").innerHTML = addVersionOne();
}

function writeVersionTwo(){
  document.getElementById("addVersionTwo").innerHTML = addVersionTwo();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <button type="button" onclick="writeVersionOne()">addVersionOne</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="writeVersionTwo()">addVersionTwo</button>
  <p id="addVersionOne">0</p>
  <p id="addVersionTwo">0</p>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because the second one executes the outer function while the first one is the outer function....

Comment: Second is an IIFE-> "Immediately invoking function expression". Search that term and do some reading

Comment: when you use `let` then it will not redeclare the variable please check this answer for clarification https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/4492504

Comment: @ZainAftab: That's not correct in this context. There is no difference between using `let` and `var` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute this:

```
addVersionOne()
```

What is the result?  Well, let's see what that function returns:

```
//...
return function() {
    counter += 1;
    return counter;
}
```

It returns a function.  That function is never executed, it's just returned.  The function itself is being set as the `innerHTML` for your target element.

But what does this return?:

```
addVersionTwo()
```

Notice how your second version wraps everything in parentheses and then adds another set of parentheses to invoke the returned function.  So while the variable `addVersionOne` is a function which returns a function, the variable `addVersionTwo` is that returned function.  And *it* returns a value:

```
//...
return counter;
```

---

*Isn't counter being reset back to 0 every time the function is run?*

Which "function" are you referring to?  You have several.  This function is being executed *once* when the page loads:

```
function () {
    let counter = 0;
    return function() {
        counter += 1; 
        return counter;
    }
}
```

It then returns a function which is stored in the `addVersionTwo` variable.  *That* function is:

```
function() {
    counter += 1; 
    return counter;
}
```

And no, that function does not reset `counter` to `0` each time it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the return value of the function addVersionOne is a function and it is obvious. But addVersionTwo function is actually the result of a function call which returns a function. So, addVersionTwo is actually the function below:

```
return function() {
    counter += 1; 
    return counter;
}
```

you could define the function addVersionTwo as follows:

```
var counter = 0;

var addVersionTwo = function() {
    counter += 1; 
    return counter;
};
```